# DSCacheFactory.get not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-cache

I use a basic example angular cache but this error appears

```js
angular.module("eliteApp",["ionic","angular-data.DSCacheFactory"])
.run(function($ionicPlatform , DSCacheFactory) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
     DSCacheFactory("leagueDataCache", { storageMode: "localStorage", maxAge: 5000, deleteOnExpire: "aggressive" });
    DSCacheFactory("leaguesCache", { storageMode: "localStorage", maxAge: 5000, deleteOnExpire: "aggressive" });
    DSCacheFactory("myTeamsCache", { storageMode: "localStorage" });
    DSCacheFactory("staticCache", { storageMode: "localStorage" });
  });
})
.factory('eliteApi',['$http','$q', '$ionicLoading','$timeout','DSCacheFactory', function( $http , $q , $ionicLoading , DSCacheFactory ,$timeout ) {

      
        var currentLeagueId;
          self.leagueDataCache = DSCacheFactory.get("leagueDataCache");
        self.leaguesCache = DSCacheFactory.get("leaguesCache");
```

```html
<script src="lib/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cache/dist/angular-cache.min.js"></script>
         <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The problem that it doesn't know function get I don't know why I `self.leagueDataCache = DSCacheFactory.get("leagueDataCache");
        self.leaguesCache = DSCacheFactory.get("leaguesCache");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line

> .factory('eliteApi',['$http','$q', '$ionicLoading','$timeout','DSCacheFactory', function( $http , $q , $ionicLoading , DSCacheFactory ,$timeout ) {

You need to declare your injected modules in the same order as you use them in function.

> $http => $http
>
> $q=> $q
>
> $ionicLoading=> $ionicLoading
>
> $timeout=> DSCacheFactory
>
> DSCacheFactory=> $timeout

so you are actually trying to use the get function of $timeout, which doesn't exist.

Grüße ausm Allgäu!